# "Error op_response:0" with prepared statement

Tags: sql, go, firebird

I'm using firebird database driver from "github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql" with GO1.11 + FB2.5

But I can't get prepared SELECT to work, it throws "Error op_response:0" error when executing the 2nd QUERYROW(). Any ideas?

Is there any alternative driver? Or am I using incorrect driver?

```
func test1(tx *sql.Tx) {
    sqlStr := "SELECT number FROM order WHERE id=?"
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(sqlStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    var value string
    err = stmt.QueryRow(123).Scan(&value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(value)

    err = stmt.QueryRow(200).Scan(&value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(value)    
}
```

Result:

```
INV20183121
panic: Error op_response:0

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.test1(0xc00009c000, 0xc0000a8200)
```

Comment: Does your server have a dummy packet interval configured? Also, do you have the full error trace?

Comment: @atlas have you checked your connection with `sql.Ping()` first.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel DummyPacketInverval is not enabled "#DummyPacketInterval = 0". Error trace from FB you mean or?

Comment: @nilsocket same result after using ` sql.Ping`

Comment: I don't know Go myself, but I'd expect information on where in the driver code the error occurred. In any case, it sounds like a driver bug. If you have something reproducible, I suggest you create an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: I did find https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/issues/29 in the tracker (it reports the same error), but I'm not sure if it is the same problem (it doesn't sound like it).

Comment: `QueryRow(123).Scan(&value)` what do "123" and "value" mean in that command? do you try too put a numeric value into string variable ? or a number (several rows) of values into a single var?

Comment: @Arioch'The `123` is a Go integer literal, `id` sounds like an integral value, and `Scan(&value)` seems to be the Go SQL API way of mapping a result column to a field. That looks perfectly normal, see also https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_Stmt The issue seems to be one internally in that driver, either with statement reuse, eg an incomplete wire protocol implementation (eg not closing the cursor before re-executing, or maybe incomplete error handling).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `id` and `number` do sound like integral values, and `123` - by common sense - should be mapped onto the query's input parameters. Maybe we here see post-effects of being exposed to de facto typeless languages like JS. Look however in your example the output field is `username` which is obviously text and it matters the receiving variable data type. However in this example the `number` column is hardly a text, but the receiving buffer is still non-ammended text variable. So, maybe not some "internal error" but good ol' type mismatch, just worded crazy way.

Comment: @Atlas try a workaround `sqlStr := "SELECT cast(number as varchar(50)) FROM order WHERE id=?"` and report if it made this work. Note: this is a bad workaround here, not to be used in production code. Just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Arioch'The you have a good point aboult " try to put a numeric value into string variable" (reading the column `number`, which is probably numeric value, into `value` which is a string). However in that case I'd expect the `err = stmt.QueryRow(200).Scan(&value)` statement to return non nil error and thus the code should panic.

Comment: @Arioch'The "Number" is already a varchar(20) in the database, the 1st query worked, but the 2nd query failed.

Answer (score 1):

I can venture a guess. Looking at `github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql` sources, [this](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/blob/d881f646c38b306528a63fc4d839cf6291d4ebef/wireprotocol.go#L1043) seems to be the only code path which can produce this error. Looking [here](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/blob/d881f646c38b306528a63fc4d839cf6291d4ebef/wireprotocol.go#L1029), it ignores any network errors returned by [`recvPackets`](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/blob/d881f646c38b306528a63fc4d839cf6291d4ebef/wireprotocol.go#L268), which means: any thing on the network socket breaks, and you get this error back (because that's what `recvPackets` returns in case of network error).

I'd suggest rebuilding your code with [`debugPrint`](https://github.com/nakagami/firebirdsql/blob/d881f646c38b306528a63fc4d839cf6291d4ebef/wireprotocol.go#L1246) code uncommented, and see what is *actually* going on on the network connection.